# Printing JSON Dictionary in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am getting the data from an API using JavaScript.

The statement `console.log(json[0])` gives the result:

```
{"id":"1","username":"ghost","points":"5","kills":"18","xp":"10","diamonds":"0","level":"1","missionscomplete":"1"}
```

Now I am trying to print the individual elements of this dictionary. How do I do this ? My code is below:

```
function loadLeaderboard(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard",function(data){
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(json[0]);
        $.each(json[i], function(key, data) {
            console.log(key + ' -> ' + data);
        });
    });
}
```

**EDIT**:
The value of data as returned by the API is

```
["{\"id\":\"1\",\"username\":\"ghost\",\"points\":\"5\",\"kills\":\"18\",\"xp\":\"10\",\"diamonds\":\"0\",\"level\":\"1\",\"missionscomplete\":\"1\"}","{\"id\":\"2\",\"username\":\"seconduser\",\"points\":\"0\",\"kills\":\"3\",\"xp\":\"0\",\"diamonds\":\"0\",\"level\":\"0\",\"missionscomplete\":\"0\"}","{\"id\":\"3\",\"username\":\"goat\",\"points\":\"12\",\"kills\":\"13\",\"xp\":\"14\",\"diamonds\":\"10\",\"level\":\"10\",\"missionscomplete\":\"4\"}"]
```

The value in json after the operation `var json = $.parseJSON(data);` is

```
["{"id":"1","username":"ghost","points":"5","kills":…diamonds":"0","level":"1","missionscomplete":"1"}", "{"id":"2","username":"seconduser","points":"0","ki…diamonds":"0","level":"0","missionscomplete":"0"}", "{"id":"3","username":"goat","points":"12","kills":…amonds":"10","level":"10","missionscomplete":"4"}"]
```

Answer (score 7):

You can just use stringify method of JSON-

`console.log(JSON.stringify(json[0]));`

Answer (score 2):

#### Update

Your JSON data is a mess. It's not in the format you want. It should be an array of objects, but instead it is an array of *strings*, where each of those strings is the JSON representation of one of your user objects.

You *could* decode this in your JavaScript code, but you shouldn't have to. The JSON API should be fixed to generate a reasonable JSON object.

I don't know what language your server code is in, but it must be doing something like this pseudocode:

```
array = []
for each userObject in leaderBoard:
    userJson = toJSON( userObject )
    array.push( userJson )
jsonOutput = toJSON( array )
```

Instead, the code should look more like this:

```
array = []
for each userObject in leaderBoard:
    array.push( userObject )
jsonOutput = toJSON( array )
```

In other words, the way to generate the JSON you want in most languages is to create an object or array with the structure you need, and then call the language's `toJSON` function (or whatever function you use) on that object or array. Let it generate all of the JSON in one fell swoop. Don't generate JSON for each individual element of your array and then generate JSON again for the entire array as a whole. That gives you an array of strings where you want an array of objects.

#### Original answer

What you're asking for is not what you really want to do.

Your JSON response returns an array of user objects, correct? That's why `json[0]` is a single object.

You probably want to loop over that *array*, but you don't loop over the individual *objects* in the array. You simply reference their properties by name.

Also, instead of using `$.get()` and `$.parseJSON()`, you can use `$.getJSON()` which parses it for you.

And one other tip: don't put the hostname and port in your URL. Use a relative URL instead, and then you can use the same URL in both development and production.

So for test purposes, let's say you want to log the `id`, `username`, and `points` for each user in your leaderboard JSON array. You could do it like this:

```
function loadLeaderboard() {
    var url = '/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard';
    $.getJSON( url, function( leaders ) {
        // leaders is an array of user objects, so loop over it
        $.each( leaders, function( i, user ) {
            // get the properties directly for the current user
            console.log( user.id, user.username, user.points );
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`json[0]` is an object, so you want to loop over the keys:

```
var o = json[0];
for (var key in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        console.log(key, o[key]);
    }
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UTyDa/

Comment: This give me: key 0 is {, key 1 is ", key 2 is i and so on

Comment: Is there some way to sort them out as key = id & value = 1, key = username & value = ghost and so on ?

Comment: What about `json[0].id`? Try it out with alert. It should work.

Comment: Then what you put in your question doesn't match the real scenario.

Comment: Hmm, the fiddle is working. But my code isn't. So the problem seems to be at this line then: `var json = $.parseJSON(data);`

Answer (score 1):

jQuery.each() is probably the easiest way, check this out: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/

eg

```
$.each(json[0], function(key, data) {
    console.log(key + ' -> ' + data);
});
```

**EDIT:**

What's the result of the following?

```
function loadLeaderboard(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard",function(data){
        var json = $.parseJSON(data);
        console.log(json[0]);
        for(var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
            $.each(json[i], function(key, data) {
                console.log(key + ' -> ' + data);
            });
        }
    });
}
```

**EDIT 2:** 'data' returned as array.

```
function loadLeaderboard(){
    $.get("http://localhost:8888/l4/public/api/v1/getLeaderboard", function(data){
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data[i]);
            console.log('Data for index: ' + i);
            $.each(json, function(key, val) {
                    console.log(key + ' -> ' + val);
            });
    }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is the error message I'm getting: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '114' in {"id":"1","username":"ghost","points":"5","kills":"18","xp":"10","diamonds":"0","level":"1","missionscomplete":"1"}`

Comment: @AshishAgarwal: Please see my updated code. If you still see errors, please share the entire json array that is delivered by the API.

Comment: Also, what's the use of var json = $.parseJSON(data); ?

Comment: Updated the question with values of data and $.parseJSON(data)

Comment: After pasting the above code, I have the error: 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '114' in {"id":"1","username":"ghost","points":"5","kills":"18","xp":"10","diamonds":"0","level":"1","missionscomplete":"1"} `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37769/discussion-between-anupam-and-ashish-agarwal)